# PagedListPager page always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

This used to work... but now the >> anchor tag of the PagedListPager always passes null to the controller for the page value required...

VS 2013 Web Express & MVC 4 with latest package updates for all.

Just like in Scot Allen's MVC 4 intro, I have a partial view with a PagedListPager

The Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Catalog(string Id= "0", int page=1)
    {

          var CurrentItemsPage = (get-data-blaw-blaw-blaw).ToPagedList(page,18);

          var model = new ShowRoomCatalogPackage(){ CurrentItems = CurrentItemsPage};

          return View(model);
    }
```

The catalog page

```
@model craftstore.Models.ShowRoomCatalogPackage

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Catalog";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Details.cshtml";
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Catalog", "Home", new { category = @Model.SelectedCategoryId, page = 1 },
                new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        UpdateTargetId = "products",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        HttpMethod = "post"
                    }
            )
        )
{
<div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-5 col-sm-4 dropdown-menu">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedCategoryId)
                @Html.DropDownList("id", Model.CategoryItems, new { @id = "ddlCategories", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-1">
            @Html.ActionLink("Your Cart", "Index", "ShoppingCart", "", new { @class = "btn btn-green btn-lg" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @Html.Partial("_CatalogPartial", Model.CurrentItems)
    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- container -->
}
<br />
<br />

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new AnimOnScroll(document.getElementById('grid'), {
            minDuration: 0.4,
            maxDuration: 0.7,
            viewportFactor: 0.2
        });
    </script>
}
```

The partial view:

```
@model IPagedList<ShowroomCatalog>

<div id="productList">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="pagedList" data-cs-target="#productList">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { category = ViewBag.SelectedCategoryId, page }), PagedListRenderOptions.MinimalWithItemCountText)
    </div>
    <ul class="grid effect-2" id="grid">
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            var path = String.Format("~/Content/Images/catalog/{0}/{1}", item.OfferType, item.ImagePath);
            <li>
                <div class="itembox">
                    <div class="imagebox">
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Detail", "Home", new { id = item.Id })" title="Detail for @item.CatalogName">
                            <img class="catalogimg" src="@Url.Content(path)" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <p>@item.CatalogName</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
</div><!-- productlist -->
```

Now the rendered partialview in the browser doesn't have anything in the anchors which may or may not be normal...

```
    <div class="pagedList" data-cs-target="#productList">
            <div class="pagination-container"><ul class="pagination"><li class="disabled PagedList-skipToPrevious"><a rel="prev">«</a></li><li class="disabled PagedList-pageCountAndLocation"><a>Showing items 1 through 18 of 65.</a></li><li class="PagedList-skipToNext"><a href="" rel="next">»</a></li></ul></div>
    </div>
```

And when you hover on the >> it doesn't show the page parameter in the URL:

[image: Hover mouse over paging control to page forward]

Again, back in the Controller - I get the category (15) but no page parameter or Request.URL parameter is passed to the controller - it's not hiding because of some routing mistake...I think...

How do I get the paging control to work again...???

[EDIT: one more note - the url path on the pager is /controller/action/category/page rather than what shows up on Scot Allen's OdeToFood example where it's equivalent would be /controller/action/category?page=n (like /Home/Catalog/15?page=1 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the JS for the PagedList class anchor element.

```
   var getPage = function () {
    var $a = $(this);

    var options = {
        url: $a.attr("href"),
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        type: "get"
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var target = $a.parents("div.pagedList").attr("data-otf-target");
        $(target).replaceWith(data);
    });
    return false;

};
```

And this is fired off by :

```
$(".main-content").on("click", ".pagedList a", getPage);
```

BUT, this means you need to have your  @RenderBody() call in your _Layout.cshtml file wrapped in something with a class of main-content. An example:

```
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
```